# Disguising Image Files In Java

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have a situation where I would like to do some very light image file obfustication. My application ships with a bunch of .png files and I'd like it if they weren't so readily editable.

I'm not looking for a 'secure' solution (I don't believe one really exists), I'd just like Joe Public to be unable to edit the files.

I am currently using;

```
ImageIO.read(new File("/images/imagefile.png"));
```

I'd rather not have to use Serialisation, as the ImageIO system is pretty deeply ingrained in the code, each image needs also to remain as its own file on disk.

I was hoping I could just change the file extension eg;

```
ImageIO.read(new File("/images/imagefile.dat"));
```

But ImageIO seems to use it to identify the file. Can I tell ImageIO that it is a PNG despite its extension?

Comment: +1 for using the word obfustication ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypt all the files on disk.
Then in the program, decrypt a file, load it in memory and go rocking.

Comment: This certainly appeals to my inner cryptonerd. I guess block ciphers would be overkill. Something silly like flipping all the bits in the file would do...(file XOR 0xff)

Comment: yes, but now that you said it publicly you can't do that anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Java image I/O uses the [Service Provider Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/package-summary.html) to support new image formats<sup>1</sup>.  I believe it might be possible to add a new decoder using a file extension.  If that is the case, there is the route to providing an easily pluggable reader for a custom image format.

Note that you will probably need to change the file extension in the source.  That might be the job for an advanced IDE, or a one-time search and replace using grep.

As to the format, one extremely simple way make media files unreadable in common readers is to write the bytes of the image in reverse order.  Then flip them back after read, put them in a `ByteArrayInputStream`, and pass them to `ImageIO.read(InputStream)`.

1. After you have written the service provider and Jar'd it properly (using a manifest with attributes to identify the file/content type it handles, and the corresponding encoder/decoder), add it to the run-time class-path of the app., and it should be able to read the custom image format.

Comment: I think it is possible by your history of answers that you have forgotten more than I know :)

Answer (score 0):

...or keep all images in a single file and `seek()` to the start position of each image as you load.  You can do this by pre-seeking against a `FileInputStream`, or conversely by creating a `ByteArrayInputStream` for `ImageIO.read(InputStream)`.

Comment: the application gets updated online automatically, and that system expects each image file to be separate as it will only really ever have to change one file at a time.

Comment: Gotcha, then file-level obfuscation it is :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Iterator rs = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("png");
ImageReader ir = (ImageReader) rs.next();
File srcFile = new File("/images/imagefile.dat");
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(srcFile);
ir.setInput(iis);
```